# iphone: how to perform Symbolication while using crash reports in xcode4

Tags: iphone, xcode

I m not getting how the Symbolication is work? How .dSYM file is created and how to convert the binary code to .dSYM file.and how to see the the .dYSM file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store and manage dysm files along with application package XCode has "Archive" option (Product -> Archive). All created archives can be accessed through Organizer (Window -> Organizer). Xcode uses this archives to symbolicate crash reports.
Import your crash reports into organizer (Devices -> Device logs) and they will be symbolicated automatically.

Comment: but where is application binary and .dSYM file is located??

Comment: Window -> Organizer -> Archives -> context menu on archive -> show in finder

Comment: thanks a lot but how .dSYM is Created..how can we see the converted symbolic file?